# Using a dictionary to update a row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am using a dict to update the values in a row of pandas dataframe like this:

```
dict = {'id': 1, 'col1': 1, 'col2': 2} # supplied by another  method

upd_dict = {key: [val] for key, val in dict.items()}
upd_row = pd.DataFrame.from_records(upd_dict, index='id')
df.update(upd_row)
```

This works well - if the updated values are not None. I would like to extend this so that the values in df can be updated to NA/NaN.

How can I elegantly update several values in a row to NA/NaN if these NA/NaN values are supplied in a dictionary (like in the code snippet)?

EDIT: I am aware that `update` cannot set cells to NA. The reason I am asking is that currently the only solution which comes to mind is to loop over all NA values in the dict and set the corresponding cells in the dataframe row to NA. But I thought there is a better way. Similar to what you can do in SQL: an UPDATE statement can update several columns. Essentially, my question is how can I update several cells in a dataframe row **at once**. `update` ticks the boxes - but only if the updated values are not NA.

Comment: You can't with `update`. It only replaces with the non-NA values of the input

Comment: @mozway Thanks - I know that `update` cannot do that. This is the reason for my post. I also know that I can write a loop to go over all NA values in the dict and set the corresponding cells in the row to NA but I thought there is a better way

Comment: I provided a couple alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, you cannot do this with [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) only,

one quick hack could be to use a placeholder for NaNs to perform the update:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records({'id': [1], 'col1': [10], 'col2': [20]},
                               index='id')

dic = {'id': 1, 'col1': 1, 'col2': float('nan')} # supplied by another  method

upd_dict = {key: [val] for key, val in dic.items()}
upd_row = pd.DataFrame.from_records(upd_dict, index='id')
df.update(upd_row.fillna('PLACEHOLDER'))
df = df.replace('PLACEHOLDER', float('nan'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
id            
1      1   NaN
```

Alternative using a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m = upd_row.isna().reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns, fill_value=False)
df = df.mask(m)
df.update(upd_row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the re-indexing really necessary? I tried only `m = upd_row.isna()` and it produces the same result

Comment: Depends on your data. No, if you have all columns in your dictionary, otherwise yes ;)

Comment: Actually, I just tried by adding 'col3' to the original df - it still works despite the dict not supplying that column.

Comment: @Nick pandas reindexes internally, assigning `NaN` on missing indices. This might be an issue as `NaN` doesn't have an unambitious boolean value. Not sure this would work with all pandas versions, but if this works well in your setup go for it.

Comment: \*unambiguous ;)